# How to improve/fix collision detection between ball and paddle?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, game-physics

Basically i am in the process of making a game which is like pong, breakout, etc. I am having some problems when the ball and paddle collide... but only sometimes!

This video here is what is occuring: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFZIxFIg0rI

So yea, basically the ball sometimes seems to go a bit crazy when it collides with the paddle... normally if i am moving the paddle in the opposite direction of which the ball is approaching it. Also the ball sometimes get's caught between the bottom of the game window and the paddle... even though i have code to stop the ball, paddle, etc from going outside of the screen...

Any ideas... or simple fixes? Thanks

Oh btw... here is the code i am using for collision detection between the ball and paddle and to stop them from going outside of the game window:

```
//CODE FOR CHECKING IF THE BALL IS OUTSIDE OF THE SCREEN

        //checks for collision with left wall
        if (pPosition.X <= 0)
        {
            pVelocity.X = -pVelocity.X;                
        }

        //checks for collision with right wall
        if (pPosition.X + pTexture.Width >= screenWidth)
        {
            pVelocity.X = -pVelocity.X;                                           
        }

        //checks for collision with top wall
        if (pPosition.Y <= 0)
        {
            pVelocity.Y = -pVelocity.Y;                
        }

        //checks for collision with bottom wall
        if (pPosition.Y + pTexture.Height >= ScreenHeight)
        {
            pVelocity.Y = -pVelocity.Y; //only need to invert Y velocity...                    
        }
    }


//CODE FOR CHECKING COLLISION BETWEEN BALL AND PADDLE

if (Ball.pRectangle.Intersects(Paddle.GetRectangle))
        {
            //Ball.pPosition.Y -= Ball.pVelocity.Y;
            Ball.pVelocity.Y = -Ball.pVelocity.Y;
        }            

        Ball.pPosition += Ball.pVelocity; //As this is in the update method, this just enables the ball to keep moving each frame...
```

*EDIT* at 17:21:

```
if (Ball.pRectangle.Intersects(Paddle.GetRectangle))
        {
            if (Ball.pRectangle.Bottom > Paddle.GetRectangle.Top)
            { //intersecting top of paddle
                //WORKING
                Ball.pPosition.Y = Paddle.GetRectangle.Top - Ball.pHeight;
                Ball.pVelocity.Y = -Ball.pVelocity.Y;
            }


 if (Ball.pRectangle.Right > Paddle.GetRectangle.Left && Ball.pRectangle.Right <     Paddle.GetRectangle.Right)
            { //intersecting left of paddle
                //WORKING
                Ball.pPosition.X = Paddle.GetRectangle.Left - Ball.pWidth;
                Ball.pVelocity.X = -Ball.pVelocity.X;
            }

 if (Ball.pRectangle.Left < Paddle.GetRectangle.Right && Ball.pRectangle.Left > Paddle.GetRectangle.Left)
            { //intersecting right of paddle
                //NOT WORKING
                Ball.pPosition.X = Paddle.GetRectangle.Right + Ball.pWidth;
                Ball.pVelocity.X = -Ball.pVelocity.X;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not that the ball gets caught between the bottom of the game window and the paddle, but it gets stuck within the paddle.

Avoid that by setting the Y coordinate of the ball to be above the paddle when you detect a hit with the paddle from the top.

If you detect a hit on the bottom of the paddle, then you have to set the Y coordinate of the ball to be below the paddle.

In the same way if you have hit from the side you have to set the X coordinate of the ball, so that it is outside of the paddle.

The point is that after the hit the panel and the ball must not touch each other, otherwise you detect a second hit immediately.

Comment: Ok, i will try that and will let you know if it works :).

Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: When it collides with the paddle from the side, if i set the ball's Y component to be above the paddle, wont that look a little unrealistic?

Comment: Oh ok, i will try that... i suppose i should have realised when you mentioned the hit from above or below the paddle that it would work the same way for a hit on the left or right side of it. This does make sense though, thanks :)

Comment: @6a6179 dont forget to mark as resolved if it fixed your problem

Comment: :D ty... It seems to be working when the ball hits the top of the paddle and also when it hits the left of the paddle but when the ball hits the right of the paddle, it doesn't seem to work properly... i have amended my question above to include the code i have written for both the top, left and right... thanks :)

Comment: the code looks correct, I dont know where Ball.pWidth comes from, that might be the problem. Furthermore I would add a slight offset to make sure that paddle and ball dont touch, eg: `Ball.pPosition.X = Paddle.GetRectangle.Right + Ball.pWidth + 0.01;` // 0.01 is the offset

Comment: Yea i was using the ball width as the offset. I will try to use the code above and get back to you regarding if it's solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... i mean sometimes when the ball hit's the top of the paddle, it respawns on the right side of the paddle. Also when the ball hits the right side of the paddle, it doesn't seem to flow in terms of it look a bit juttery (for use of a better word... lol) so it seems to accelerate or have the effect of slightly lagging. Thanks

Comment: The reason i added 2 conditions for the collision with the left side of the paddle is the first condition is true also when the ball collides with the right side of the paddle as well as the left side, so i used additional conditions to differentiate between them. Thanks :)

Comment: ok I see, what you need is `else if` statements instead of just `if` because multiple hit conditions may be true at once, for instance a collission from top might be interpreted as a collission from the side at the same time with your code

Comment: ok, so should i use else if statement's or would it also work if i just used something like if (condition 1 & condition 2... etc)? Thanks thumbmunkeys

Comment: try the else ifs, it still will not be 100% accurate. You would get a much more accurate colission detection if you treat the previous and current ball position as vector and then see which side of the paddle intersects the vector

Comment: ok, so i have listed the relation of all sides of the ball when it collides with each side of the paddle. I have also used the else if instead of just if's... and tbh it works fine apart from the when the ball collides with the right side, which isn't so much incorrect as it is a bit unrealstic but tbh i really dont care anymore lol... as i have been trying to fix collision problems for way too long now... i mean for a small game like this, as it's not going to be the next AAA game LOL so i don't think 100% correct detection is necessary. Thanks v much for your time and help :)

Comment: Yea, the ball still sometimes when the ball hits the right wall and the right side of the paddle at the same time, it gets stuck along the bottom of the screen and it starts going backwards and forwards... so it get's stuck in the bottom of the screen going backwards and forwards.

Comment: :) I will try to enjoy it a bit more