# Find collision areas on the picturebox, windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am a newbie in C#, I am trying to build a Ping Pong Game in C#, till now I have been able to achieve the angular movement of the ball inside the panel of my windows forms using the timer functions as follows:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radians = (Angle(_start, _end) - 180) * -1;
        isFirstTime = true;
        timer.Interval = 25;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        middle.X -= Convert.ToInt16(interval * Math.Cos(radians));
        middle.Y -= Convert.ToInt16(interval * Math.Sin(radians));
        pictureBox2.Location = middle;

        //pictureBox1 is the paddle and pictureBox2 is the ball....

        if (IsTouching(pictureBox2, pictureBox1))  //Custom method to check whether the two picture boxes touch each other.
        {
            double relativeLocation = Math.Abs(((double)panel1.Left - (double)pictureBox2.Left) / (double)pictureBox2.Width);
            timer.Stop();               
            timer2.Interval = 25;
            timer2.Tick += Timer2_Tick;                }
            timer2.Start();
        }
    }  
    private void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isFirstTime = false;
        middle.X += Convert.ToInt16(interval * Math.Cos(radians));
        middle.Y += Convert.ToInt16(interval * Math.Sin(radians)); 
        pictureBox2.Location = middle;
        if (pictureBox2.Left < panel1.Left)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

This is just the start of my project and yes there would be many issues in this code also, but currently the issue which i am facing is that when the ball hits the paddle i need to determine whether on which side of the paddle the ball has hit, on the right or on the left side or maybe in the center, and according to that i have to set the angled movement of the ball, right side movement if the ball hits the right side of the paddle, left side movement for the left side of the paddle and horizontally upwards for the center part.

I tried using `double relativeLocation = Math.Abs(((double)panel1.Left - (double)pictureBox2.Left) / (double)pictureBox2.Width)` method to determine some relative location on the paddle but I am still not able to achieve what I am trying to do. I am very much confused as how to proceed right now.

In short I have to determine the portion of the paddle at the time when the ball hits the paddle, in order to give the desired angular movement to the ball.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve/fix collision detection between ball and paddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351167/how-to-improve-fix-collision-detection-between-ball-and-paddle)

Comment: Only add an event handler once.  You are adding the second tick handler on every tick of the first timer, so it's running that code multiple times on each tick.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the ball is `pictureBox2`
and the left paddle is `pictureBox1`...

In this situation, you must check `pictureBox1.Right`
 and 
`pictureBox2.Left`
.

Code example:

```
if (pictureBox1.Right == pictureBox2.Left)
{
    //Collision
}
```